# Can't call function in parent component from child component using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 files:

grid-body.jsx (GridBody) and grid-row.jsx (GridRow)

In GridBody, I declared a function showAlert which I pass to every GridRow:

```
var GridBody = React.createClass({
    showAlert: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },

    render: function() {
        var rows = this.props.rows.map(function(li) {
            return (
                <GridRow showAlert={this.showAlert} />
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {rows}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

And in GridRow:

```
var GridRow = React.createClass({
    toggle: function() {
        this.props.showAlert('HEY');        // -----> ERROR - not a function
    },

    render: function() {
        <div>
            <a href="#" onClick={this.toggle} />
        </div>
    }
});
```

I'm trying to call the showAlert from parent and based on the examples I've seen, this is how to do it but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using the wrong value for `this` inside of `GridView.render`.  Either pass it explicitly to `Array.map()` (see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for how to do that) or assign `this` to some new variable at the very top of `render()` and reference that instead.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/635678) is a really, really great SO comment as to why this happens, as well as some other alternative workarounds if neither of the above work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The context of the function passed to map in render method of GridBody is window and not the component. You can bind the interatee to get the behavior you want:

```
render: function() {
    var rows = this.props.rows.map(function(li) {
        return (
            <GridRow showAlert={this.showAlert} />
        );
    }.bind(this));

    return (
        <div>
            {rows}
        </div>
    );
}
```